# How to recover a branch on remote that has been deleted mistakenly by someone else in Git

Tags: git, gitlab

Our team has placed the code repository on the Gitlab. Someone has deleted a branch on remote Gitlab repository by mistake. I was working on that branch and I have this branch locally on my system. Can anyone tell me how i can again restore this branch on remote. Can anyone guide me in this regard.

Comment: Just push it again from another local that has it _or_ push a know ID where the branch was before with `git push some-remote some-commit-id:refs/heads/some-branch`

Comment: you may also want to add the `--mirror` flag on the push to preserve git history